# Python Issue - Correlated Random Samples and Cholesky Decomposition

Tags: python, numpy, random, statistics, covariance

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import cholesky

X1_temp = np.random.normal(0, 1, (40, 10)) # with mean 0 and std. dev. 1
C = cholesky(C0, lower = False)
X1 = X1_temp @ np.transpose(C)
```

Thanks very much in advance. This is just a very simple task. I am given a desired covariance matrix C0. I want to generate random correlated data matrix X1 such that the covariance matrix of X1 is C0. I use Cholesky Decomposition. The codes are in Python.

However, if I then manually use np.cov() to calculate the covariance matrix of X1, it turns out to be quite different from C0. Please see below for the results.

```
C0
array([[0.00119545, 0.00055428, 0.00094478, 0.00057466, 0.00039038,
        0.0004846 , 0.00047505, 0.00039403, 0.00041767, 0.00053985],
       [0.00055428, 0.00055869, 0.0005272 , 0.00046757, 0.0002733 ,
        0.00037907, 0.00034639, 0.00030749, 0.00034975, 0.00041578],
       [0.00094478, 0.0005272 , 0.00163294, 0.00049306, 0.00032083,
        0.0004176 , 0.000403  , 0.00038588, 0.00037359, 0.00050818],
       [0.00057466, 0.00046757, 0.00049306, 0.00161212, 0.00065667,
        0.00080889, 0.00075579, 0.00048425, 0.00066279, 0.00044288],
       [0.00039038, 0.0002733 , 0.00032083, 0.00065667, 0.00076096,
        0.00054659, 0.00061203, 0.00032021, 0.00047247, 0.00025952],
       [0.0004846 , 0.00037907, 0.0004176 , 0.00080889, 0.00054659,
        0.00116606, 0.00056961, 0.00040392, 0.00053751, 0.00033647],
       [0.00047505, 0.00034639, 0.000403  , 0.00075579, 0.00061203,
        0.00056961, 0.0008417 , 0.0003747 , 0.00054147, 0.00033309],
       [0.00039403, 0.00030749, 0.00038588, 0.00048425, 0.00032021,
        0.00040392, 0.0003747 , 0.00042903, 0.00035186, 0.00030802],
       [0.00041767, 0.00034975, 0.00037359, 0.00066279, 0.00047247,
        0.00053751, 0.00054147, 0.00035186, 0.00061011, 0.00033744],
       [0.00053985, 0.00041578, 0.00050818, 0.00044288, 0.00025952,
        0.00033647, 0.00033309, 0.00030802, 0.00033744, 0.00048086]])

np.cov(X1,rowvar=False)
array([[ 2.73579114e-03,  1.11107458e-03,  7.39905489e-04,
         8.80909471e-04,  2.67940563e-04,  3.00456896e-04,
         2.78558784e-04,  1.95630006e-04, -8.84664656e-07,
         3.07873704e-04],
       [ 1.11107458e-03,  7.67420975e-04,  6.32049491e-05,
         7.29592024e-04,  2.30491196e-04,  2.16890868e-04,
         1.67582787e-04,  8.49125674e-05, -8.34866957e-06,
         1.68615033e-04],
       [ 7.39905489e-04,  6.32049491e-05,  1.14805709e-03,
        -2.24580150e-04,  8.49680219e-05, -1.42327782e-05,
        -1.19349618e-04, -1.75276890e-05,  3.43158455e-05,
         6.89819740e-05],
       [ 8.80909471e-04,  7.29592024e-04, -2.24580150e-04,
         1.44999733e-03,  1.27584928e-04,  3.49017835e-04,
         1.89078071e-04,  4.95665628e-05, -3.51667683e-05,
         1.25940711e-04],
       [ 2.67940563e-04,  2.30491196e-04,  8.49680219e-05,
         1.27584928e-04,  4.63007494e-04,  1.58792113e-04,
         5.37907654e-05,  5.71734068e-05,  2.18693890e-05,
         7.16343773e-05],
       [ 3.00456896e-04,  2.16890868e-04, -1.42327782e-05,
         3.49017835e-04,  1.58792113e-04,  4.23799861e-04,
         1.37080444e-05,  9.08977322e-06, -6.28273606e-05,
         6.64415798e-06],
       [ 2.78558784e-04,  1.67582787e-04, -1.19349618e-04,
         1.89078071e-04,  5.37907654e-05,  1.37080444e-05,
         2.33866264e-04,  6.65816973e-05,  1.84881869e-05,
         5.54885576e-05],
       [ 1.95630006e-04,  8.49125674e-05, -1.75276890e-05,
         4.95665628e-05,  5.71734068e-05,  9.08977322e-06,
         6.65816973e-05,  2.04723105e-04,  3.60286054e-05,
         4.11557090e-05],
       [-8.84664656e-07, -8.34866957e-06,  3.43158455e-05,
        -3.51667683e-05,  2.18693890e-05, -6.28273606e-05,
         1.84881869e-05,  3.60286054e-05,  1.43719872e-04,
         9.74047167e-06],
       [ 3.07873704e-04,  1.68615033e-04,  6.89819740e-05,
         1.25940711e-04,  7.16343773e-05,  6.64415798e-06,
         5.54885576e-05,  4.11557090e-05,  9.74047167e-06,
         1.24753756e-04]])
```

Comment: FYI: The NumPy random module has a method for generating samples from the multivariate normal distribution for a given covariance matrix: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.multivariate_normal.html

Comment: FYI (part 2): https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/CorrelatedRandomSamples.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't transpose `C` when you compute `X1`.

```
In [33]: C0
Out[33]: 
array([[0.00119545, 0.00055428, 0.00094478, 0.00057466, 0.00039038,
        0.0004846 , 0.00047505, 0.00039403, 0.00041767, 0.00053985],
       [0.00055428, 0.00055869, 0.0005272 , 0.00046757, 0.0002733 ,
        0.00037907, 0.00034639, 0.00030749, 0.00034975, 0.00041578],
       [0.00094478, 0.0005272 , 0.00163294, 0.00049306, 0.00032083,
        0.0004176 , 0.000403  , 0.00038588, 0.00037359, 0.00050818],
       [0.00057466, 0.00046757, 0.00049306, 0.00161212, 0.00065667,
        0.00080889, 0.00075579, 0.00048425, 0.00066279, 0.00044288],
       [0.00039038, 0.0002733 , 0.00032083, 0.00065667, 0.00076096,
        0.00054659, 0.00061203, 0.00032021, 0.00047247, 0.00025952],
       [0.0004846 , 0.00037907, 0.0004176 , 0.00080889, 0.00054659,
        0.00116606, 0.00056961, 0.00040392, 0.00053751, 0.00033647],
       [0.00047505, 0.00034639, 0.000403  , 0.00075579, 0.00061203,
        0.00056961, 0.0008417 , 0.0003747 , 0.00054147, 0.00033309],
       [0.00039403, 0.00030749, 0.00038588, 0.00048425, 0.00032021,
        0.00040392, 0.0003747 , 0.00042903, 0.00035186, 0.00030802],
       [0.00041767, 0.00034975, 0.00037359, 0.00066279, 0.00047247,
        0.00053751, 0.00054147, 0.00035186, 0.00061011, 0.00033744],
       [0.00053985, 0.00041578, 0.00050818, 0.00044288, 0.00025952,
        0.00033647, 0.00033309, 0.00030802, 0.00033744, 0.00048086]])

In [34]: C = cholesky(C0, lower=False)

In [35]: n = 40

In [36]: X1_temp = np.random.normal(0, 1, (n, 10)) # with mean 0 and std. dev. 1

In [37]: X1 = X1_temp @ C

In [38]: np.cov(X1, rowvar=False)
Out[38]: 
array([[0.00170434, 0.00091094, 0.00134416, 0.00056663, 0.00063199,
        0.00050691, 0.00052851, 0.00058113, 0.00070497, 0.00094468],
       [0.00091094, 0.00076975, 0.00085689, 0.00042849, 0.00033691,
        0.00022588, 0.00031262, 0.00043736, 0.00043965, 0.00068883],
       [0.00134416, 0.00085689, 0.00177699, 0.00060582, 0.00059343,
        0.00035828, 0.00047125, 0.00062899, 0.00069686, 0.00082439],
       [0.00056663, 0.00042849, 0.00060582, 0.00107095, 0.0004217 ,
        0.00037837, 0.00038153, 0.00043858, 0.00043721, 0.00037525],
       [0.00063199, 0.00033691, 0.00059343, 0.0004217 , 0.00079374,
        0.00042106, 0.00051381, 0.00035244, 0.00050983, 0.00024706],
       [0.00050691, 0.00022588, 0.00035828, 0.00037837, 0.00042106,
        0.00080684, 0.0003886 , 0.00021881, 0.00042829, 0.00023707],
       [0.00052851, 0.00031262, 0.00047125, 0.00038153, 0.00051381,
        0.0003886 , 0.00057768, 0.00029707, 0.00039979, 0.0002629 ],
       [0.00058113, 0.00043736, 0.00062899, 0.00043858, 0.00035244,
        0.00021881, 0.00029707, 0.00042199, 0.00034844, 0.00040239],
       [0.00070497, 0.00043965, 0.00069686, 0.00043721, 0.00050983,
        0.00042829, 0.00039979, 0.00034844, 0.00058689, 0.00043979],
       [0.00094468, 0.00068883, 0.00082439, 0.00037525, 0.00024706,
        0.00023707, 0.0002629 , 0.00040239, 0.00043979, 0.00077079]])
```

For testing, you'll get a more convincing result if you use more samples.

```
In [39]: n = 400

In [40]: X1_temp = np.random.normal(0, 1, (n, 10)) # with mean 0 and std. dev. 1

In [41]: X1 = X1_temp @ C

In [42]: np.cov(X1, rowvar=False)
Out[42]: 
array([[0.00123199, 0.00055531, 0.00096428, 0.0006604 , 0.00046758,
        0.00060183, 0.00056823, 0.00041429, 0.00046345, 0.00056343],
       [0.00055531, 0.00054127, 0.00055571, 0.00048491, 0.00028983,
        0.00038863, 0.0003752 , 0.00029274, 0.0003503 , 0.0004217 ],
       [0.00096428, 0.00055571, 0.00154136, 0.00062761, 0.00042062,
        0.00050582, 0.0004616 , 0.00043355, 0.00044465, 0.00056019],
       [0.0006604 , 0.00048491, 0.00062761, 0.00152187, 0.00065816,
        0.0008483 , 0.0007723 , 0.00051182, 0.00069478, 0.00049743],
       [0.00046758, 0.00028983, 0.00042062, 0.00065816, 0.00081247,
        0.00057251, 0.00069877, 0.00033519, 0.00050191, 0.00030041],
       [0.00060183, 0.00038863, 0.00050582, 0.0008483 , 0.00057251,
        0.00130518, 0.00059381, 0.00044213, 0.00057237, 0.00039522],
       [0.00056823, 0.0003752 , 0.0004616 , 0.0007723 , 0.00069877,
        0.00059381, 0.00097244, 0.00039577, 0.00059776, 0.00038547],
       [0.00041429, 0.00029274, 0.00043355, 0.00051182, 0.00033519,
        0.00044213, 0.00039577, 0.00044904, 0.00036922, 0.00033238],
       [0.00046345, 0.0003503 , 0.00044465, 0.00069478, 0.00050191,
        0.00057237, 0.00059776, 0.00036922, 0.00062956, 0.00037302],
       [0.00056343, 0.0004217 , 0.00056019, 0.00049743, 0.00030041,
        0.00039522, 0.00038547, 0.00033238, 0.00037302, 0.00050632]])
```